# Create more imagelist at runtime

Tags: c#, imagelist

Hello how to create 2 or more imagelist at runtime.
Example:

```
 for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++)
 {
    ImageList imageList+c = new ImageList();
 }
```

I have to imagelist name add int c number and create imagelist.(sorry my bad english)

I want Output:

imageList0

imageList1

imageList2

imageList3

imageList4

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. What do you want exactly ? An array of ImageList ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to do it in a different way like storing it into a list.

```
List<ImageList> imgList = new List<ImageList>();
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    imgList.Add(new ImageList());                
}

// get the first imgList Images.Count property
int imgCnt = imgList[0].Images.Count;
```